# Ember naming for routes and controllers

Tags: ember.js

I have a router like this:

```
//italian
this.resource('eng', function(){    
    this.route('home');
    this.resource('eng.activity', {path: 'activity'}, function() {
        this.route('insertActivity', {path: 'insert-activity'});
        this.route('listActivities', {path: 'list-activity'});
    });
});
```

Then i have for example this route:
App.EngActivityInsertActivityRoute

Is there a way to use a shorter name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Ember uses [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), so the route names are automatically generated. You could always use shorter route names in your router